# Why not working /%postname%/ with ajax serverinterval?

Tags: permalinks, jquery

I use ajax server interval for load new entries, and if I use this method the function return 404 in 30 second.
If I use default link strukture,work fine.
The mod_rewrite is enabled on my server...

The ajax part:

```
<script>
 (function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var refreshId = setInterval(function()
    {
      $('#content').fadeOut("fast").load('new.php').fadeIn("fast");
    }, 30000);
  });
})(jQuery);

</script>
```

The PHP:

```
<?php require_once("wp-blog-header.php"); ?>
  <div id="content" <?php cyberchimps_filter_content_class(); ?>>

        <?php do_action( 'cyberchimps_before_content'); ?>

        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                <?php get_template_part( 'content',       get_post_format() ); ?>

            <?php endwhile; ?>

        <?php elseif ( current_user_can( 'edit_posts' ) ) : ?>

            <?php get_template_part( 'no-results', 'index' ); ?>

        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php do_action( 'cyberchimps_after_content'); ?>

    </div>
```

If I not use the ajax,this function work fine.

My htaccess file content:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /test/
RewriteRule ^index.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . test/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

My test site:
[My test site](http://neocsatblog.mblx.hu/test/)

(Don't worry the other problem like,the page not load or text bugs thats not important.
This erorr(links erorr) also have on my live site,if I enable the pretty permalinks,but now i disabled)
I dont why not working:D
Please help me...

Comment: Does `new.php` exist? I'm guessing in the same directory as `index.php`. Have you tried a full URL in your jQuery?

Comment: Yeah,new.php content is "The PHP:" section on my post.
And yeah,i try,but nothing change

Comment: Maybe you don't understand. What is the full URL for the page and for `new.php`? I have a feeling your jQuery is trying to open www.yoursite.com/new.php but it's probably located in your theme/plugin directory. Try using the FULL URL to `new.php` in your jQuery.

Comment: http://neocsatblog.mblx.hu/test/new.php (thats becouse here the wp-header)

Comment: 2 diffrend version.
On my live site use the reletive path,on my test site use Full url,but  not working

Comment: try `load('/test/new.php')`

Comment: Post [debugging information](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) and do the right thing and [use the AJAX API](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A21376+AJAX+API)

Comment: Waldermort still not work,s_ha_dum i check it now,please wait a minute

Comment: s_ha_dum "use the AJAX API" link is brocken, i set debuging true but I nothing see...

Comment: Google is your friend http://wp.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/18/how-to-use-ajax-in-wordpress/

Comment: I'm not see the solution, you see it?